# Why jQuery.data() bugs with Raphael svg paths?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, raphael

I have a problem with [jQuery .data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5) and [Raphael's SVG path()](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.path).

I wrote a [little example](http://jsfiddle.net/NFQRH/) to explain.

```
paper = Raphael(0, 0, 600, 600)
polygon = paper.path('M19,20L24,83L106,62L112,23Z')
polygon.data('test', 'I need this info later!')
polygon.attr({"fill":"orange"})

$(document).on('click', onClick)

function onClick() {
    console.log('click')
    if(event.target.nodeName === 'path') {
        // how do i get data('test') ?

        // console.log(this.data('test')) // Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'data' 
        console.log($(this).data('test')) // undefined
        // console.log(event.target.data('test')) // Uncaught TypeError: Object #<SVGPathElement> has no method 'data' 
        console.log($(event.target).data('test')) // undefined

        // But jquery.remove() does work?
        $(event.target).remove()

    }
}
```

As you can see, I made a polygon, filled it with a color, and added an event listener to the document. On every click I check the target. If this is a polygon, I want to get its data.

Notice that in my real code, I generate tons of polygons like this. So a simple `polygon.data()` won't help. My only solution is using the event.target as reference.
[Example of multiple polygons](http://jsfiddle.net/NFQRH/1/)

How can I receive the data values?

Comment: It clearly shows a way to add data via an attribute namespace, something you could do to circumvent your issue. Do you only want to use jquery data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close, you just need the node wrapped in a jquery object to set the data first:

```
$(polygon.node).data('test', 'I need this info later!');
```

I updated your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NFQRH/2/) to show it working.

Comment: Thanks, I was a little scary about the notice on Raphael.node `Gives you a reference to the DOM object, so you can assign event handlers or just mess around. Note: Don’t mess with it.` But it works!! Thanks!